# Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue) using Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swift3, swifty-json

I have tried a lot of things now and are still getting:
*Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)'*

UPDATE:
I scan a barcode and save the info:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let expiryDate = (calendar as NSCalendar).date(byAdding: .month, value: 3, to: Date(), options: [])?.description

let barcode = BarcodeData(barcodeValue: value,
                          datetime: dateTime,
                          expiryDate: expiryDate!,
                          latitude: latitude.description,
                          longitude: longitude.description,
                          status: txtStatus.text!,
                          type: txtType.text!,
                          extraText: "")
```

Object are then mapped to a JSON string, it seems that the slashes (/) are added by this function:

```
let jsonBarcode = Mapper<BarcodeData>().toJSONString(barcode)
```

The barcode are then added to a list of String:

```
barcodeDataList.append(jsonBarcode)
```

When I click a button I invoke the web service, that anticipate parameters in the form of:

```
let testParams : Parameters =
    [ "udid": "my_udid",
       "data": jsonArray
    ]
```

jsonArray consist of an array of the BarcodeData-object(s) as seen above.

Communication with the web service looks like:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: testParams, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).validate().responseJSON { response in

                switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    print("Validation successful")

                    if let json = response.result.value {
                        print("JSON: \(json)")
                    }

                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }
```

The following is passed to the ws:

```
    ["udid": "\"001-my_udid\"", "data": [
    "{\"latitude\":\"0.0\",\"status\":\"Empty\",\"datetime\":\"2016-09-20 05:10\",\"longitude\":\"0.0\",\"type\":\"ABC123\",\"barcodevalue\":\"123456\"}"
]]
```

The json array for "data" validates at jsonlint.com and the response from the server is in the form of a json object like:

```
{result: "Data successfully received"}
```

Comment: what are those values Parameters and jsonArray?

Comment: Try to replace  \"  in your response JSON with " in IOS end and rest of the things will be fine.

Comment: Abdul: As you can see on my edited post it seems that ObjectMappers function are adding the slashes (/).

Comment: As far as I know it is okay to have slashes in a JSON object according to the specification. 
So it shouldn't be the issue here, unless if Alamofire does not support it. Which would be weird since Alamofire are often used with ObjectMapper which actually adds the slash symbols.

Answer (score 3):

Change your encoding in request from  encoding: JSONEncoding.default to encoding: URLEncoding.default

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to encode your array in json object try something like this

```
    do{
        let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(mappingArray, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        let mappedString : String = (String(data: data , encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        return mappedString
    }
    catch{
        print(error)
        return error as! String
    }
```

Append this string with your url

Comment: I wrapped the code snippet in a function but the result was only that even more slashes are being added :-(